# Correct usage of Timer in a C# webapplication

Tags: c#, timer

I have been looking extensively for examples on how to correctly use the timer feature in C# to trigger a function. The function here which is called **GetIntStatus()** basically aggregates data from several databases and stores in a seperate database. I need to run this function in a interval of every 2 hours to refresh the data and then that data will be pulled into a grid (this part I have it covered). Can someone show me how best to handle this situation ?

Comment: Nontrivial task because you said it needs to run in the context of a web app. This is one solution: http://hangfire.io/

Comment: why is this in a webapplication? if the data is all server side then why not a console application that runs on the server?

Comment: This shouldn't be in a web application.  This should be either in a Windows Service or a scheduled Console Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way to use `Timer` in WebAplication is not to use timers at all.

Alternative approaches for long running/repeating tasks:

- scheduled tasks on server side (external process with Windows or any other scheduling tools).
- ping data with script scheduled to run repeatedly
- re-request data from client browser (assuming it is opened all the time)
- use cache and configure items to re-request on expiration.

Sometimes it is ok to use short-lived timers to handle timeouts during request. I.e. `Task.Delay` may be used to force timeout when run in parallel with some other potentially long task.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure how GetIntStatus() is implemented but I had to do something similar.  Basically, you just start a timer, set an interval, and set some method to get called when the interval has elapsed.

Here's the syntax:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Start();
timer.Interval = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 minute updates
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => PerformUpdates();
```

In my case, the PefromUpdates() was an async method that returned a Task.

Comment: This will not work in a web application, the application will be recycled and your timer will not start until you get your next visitor to the website.

Comment: Can you provide me with a full syntax ?

Comment: Yes forgot to mention, this is performed in a self- hosted WCF service. Admittedly, this works in only specific cases as Scott Chamberlain mentions.

Comment: If that WCF service is hosted on IIS it still has the same problem, only if the service was "Self Hosted" would it not be a problem.

Comment: @EmaadShehzzad See [Alexei's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31037101/80274) his solution is the correct, reliable, one. Also see [Martin's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036921/correct-usage-of-timer-in-a-c-sharp-webapplication#comment50098059_31036921) for a example of a good "other scheduling tool".